# Shell Script - Removing portions of strings. Can't find Files

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a pretty simple shell script.  It reads something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo upload trigram
bteq < load_temp_trigram

echo load bigram
bteq < load_temp_bigram

echo load word
bteq < load_temp_word

echo load phrase
bteq < load_temp_phrase
```

I get the following errors, and then it the script executes the following command

```
: command not found
upload trigram
: No such file or directoryigram
: command not found
load bigram
: No such file or directorygram
: command not found
load word
: No such file or directoryord
: command not found
load phrase
```

I'm calling the script with bash script.sh or sh script.sh.

So, it looks like it isn't recognizing the echo command, even though it seems to work.  And it is cutting off pieces of the strings/files - which is probably why it can't find them.  I'm at a loss as to what's going on here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your file has CR+LF line endings.  Use `dos2unix` or some other utility to remove CR.

Comment: It actually looks like it is recognising the "echo" - as the output you are seeing that does not start with a ":"

Comment: bteq is a FTP-like client... you are dialoguing with it by means of redirection which is one-way and not quite a sane way of doing it. The multiple errors are the result of what you are feeding bteq.  Try to use the "expect" commands or build a dialogue capable wrapperscript. Without knowing what you are feeding bteq, we can't say what the error is

Answer (score 0):

1)add an -x to shell like this

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

it will reduce amount of questions in general.

2) in case you want the text output use quotes
like this

```
echo "upload trigram"
```

3) use absolute paths to the executable
like this

```
/usr/bin/bteq
```

the path to your bteq executable could be found by executing

```
which bteq
```

(if you are lucky and have a which installed)
same goes for sql batch files

```
/path/to/td_bins/bteq < /path/to/batch/load_temp_word
```

if you in the folder with batch files, relative path to it will be `./`